# Upgrading from BIRT 2.1.2; Platform.createFactoryObject() returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, birt

Management wants me to migrate a project that uses BIRT 2.1.2/Java 4/IBM WebSphere 5/Windows 2003 to Linux/Apache/Tomcat.  I've chosen Tomcat 8, Java 8, and BIRT 4.5, to maximize the time before we again fall off the trailing edge.

I'm stuck on a failing test case that just initializes BIRT, with this code:

```
public static void init( String engineHome, String Birt_Resource_Path) 
throws BirtException 
{
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
        DesignConfig config = new DesignConfig();
//      config.setBIRTHome( engineHome);
        Platform.startup( config);
        IDesignEngineFactory factory = 
            (IDesignEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject( 
                IDesignEngineFactory.EXTENSION_DESIGN_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        if (factory == null) {
            log.warn("Failed to construct DesignEngineFactory");
            initialized = false;
        } else {
            birtEngine = factory.createDesignEngine(config);
            birtResourcePath = Birt_Resource_Path; 
        }

        log.info("DesignEngineService initialized! " + engineHome);
    }
}
```

My test case calls this code, and later tests if the engine is initialized and fails then.

I read the notes about changes in BIRT 3.7 meaning I don't have to call `config.setBIRTHome( engineHome)`, so I commented out that line.

The call to `Platform.createFactoryObject(...)` is still returning null, so I get the log message "Failed to construct DesignEngineFactory" and my test case fails.

I am using Eclipse Mars, and Maven for build and dependencies.  My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.lxnx.sysman.webstar</groupId>
<artifactId>reportService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>2.0-DEVELOPMENT</version>
<name>Report Service</name>
<url>http://myproject.mycompany.com/ReportService</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <birt-version>4.5.0a</birt-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${birt-version}</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>opennms</groupId>
    <artifactId>opennms-joesnmp</artifactId>
    <version>20031201-173122</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReportServiceImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
        <additionalClasspathElement>c:\mycompany\app\myproject\bin\jars\sqljdbc42.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
      </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
<finalName>ReportService</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

It looks like all the BIRT jars are in the Maven Dependencies library; at least org.eclipse.birt.runtime-4.5.0a.jar is there along with a hundred others.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: I went through all of the versions of BIRT available at Maven Central.  Here are the results:

Comment: 4.5.0a fails my test case as described above 
4.5.0 fails to build
4.4.2 works
4.4.1 works
4.4.0 works
4.3.1 fails my test case with Xerces issues
4.3.0 fails to build
4.2.2 fails my test case with Xerces issues
4.2.1 fails to build
4.2.0 works 
3.7.2.v20120214-1408 works

Comment: So I'm going to resolve this by using 4.4.2.